Elliptic curves of rank 1 over number fields
I am interested what is known about the following statement:
For every number field $K$, there exists an elliptic curve $E$ defined over $K$ with algebraic rank equal to $1$.
Is this statement known to be true unconditionally? If not, has this been conjectured anywhere in the literature?

See this related question. The references in the question prove this result conditionally on some standard conjectures.

Thanks a lot for linking this question! I am aware of the Mazur--Rubin reference, and would be specifically interested in what (if anything) is known unconditionally.

@P.Koymans There's a preprint of Bhargava Shankar Wang "Geometry-of-numbers methods over global fields II" which calculates the average 3 Selmer group over a general number field. Then assuming that TS groups are finite and a version of the p-parity conjecture over $K$ one should be able to deduce that a positive density of elliptic curves have rank 1, generalizing the argument of Theorem 41 of "Ternary cubic forms having bounded invariants..."-Bhargava Shankar. One can also look into the paper of Bhargava and Skinner in the JRMS but I think that will also require some version of p-parity.
